# Fetch the values as List from the mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, collections

I have the following document called "empdept_rw", here I am trying to fetch the values as a list of all the available documents for a particular key.
Query Statement :

```
db.empdept_rw.find({"tremployeeid" : {"$in":db.employee_rw.distinct('tremployeeid')}}, {trDepartmentID : 1, _id :0})
```

Current output:

```
{ "trDepartmentID" : "1234" }
{ "trDepartmentID" : "1235" }
```

Expected output:

```
["1234","1235"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$group` in an Aggregation Pipeline:

```
db.empdept_rw.aggregate([
   { $match: { tremployeeid: { $in: db.employee_rw.distinct('tremployeeid') } } },
   {
      $group: { _id: null, trDepartmentID: { $push: "$trDepartmentID" } }
   }
]).toArray().shift().trDepartmentID
```